# How to avoid last piped ErrorObservable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I need to re-try an action for 5 times, then, if it has success, return his value, but if all 5 attempets fail, i need to throw an error.

I wrote this following, but it does not work because always end with last ErrorObservable.create ("rxjs": "5.5.6")

```
this.http.post<JsonResponse>(this.resourceUrl + event.body.data.id, { observe: "response" }).pipe(
  map(result => {
    if(result.data.status === "WAITING"){
      throw "WAITING";  
    }
    return result
  }) 
)
.pipe(
  retryWhen((errors) => {
    return errors
      .pipe(delay(2000))
      .pipe(take(5));
  })
)
.pipe(
  concat(
    ErrorObservable.create(
      new HttpErrorResponse({
        error: "error",
        headers: null,
        status: 500,
        statusText: "Error",
        url: "",
      })
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

@Zerotwelve has the right idea. Though here is a solution that matches the original intent of your code.

```
// declare your error inside the class
static httpError = new HttpErrorResponse({
  error: "error",
  headers: null,
  status: 500,
  statusText: "Error",
  url: "",
});

this.http.post<JsonResponse>(`${this.resourceUrl}${event.body.data.id}`, { observe: "response" })
.pipe(
  tap(result => if(result.data.status === "WAITING") throw "WAITING"),
  retry(5),
  catchError(e=>of(this.httpError))
);
```

You can use `tap()` as it will always return the same value it receives, unless you throw an error.

The `retry(5)` operator will restart the observable should an error occur. Once  it errors 5 times, then it proceeds with throwing the error.

To keep things a little cleaner, I moved your default error object to a static property. The `catchError()` expects you to return an observable. The `of()` operator will emit the parameter as an observable, which in this case is your error object.

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```js
this.http.post<JsonResponse>(this.resourceUrl + event.body.data.id, { observe: "response" }).pipe(
      retry(5),
      catchError(err => this.handleError(err))
      // [...] cour code
```